# Compile Java Program in Eclipse with Older JRE Without Installing

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I want my program to work for people with older versions of Java. My program doesn't need any special new features and it should be able to run fine in Java 6. I have Java 8 installed, and I want to know how I would go about compiling my program in Eclipse in an older version of Java without having to install Java 6.

Comment: Change your compliance version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- In the Project Explorer view, right-click on the project and then select **Properties**.
- Select the Java Compiler page in the in the **Properties** window.
- In the JDK Compliance section, select the desired **Compiler compliance level.**
- Click **Apply** and then **Ok**.

It will automatically compile to the right version

Note this doesn't actually change the version, just that the compiler would be able to enforce the **rules** that another Java version would. So it should be compatible

For cross verfiying if it is compiled properly with the lower version, 
1. Go to properties
2. go to java build path
3. go to libraries,
4. click on JRE System Library-- double click this to see if exceution environment is properly set.

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't change the version of Java that code compiles with. It will still compile using the given version of the JDK, but the compliance level tells the compiler to enforce the rules for the specified version _as if_ it were being compiled with that version. Subtle point worth mentioning.

Comment: @RyanJ okay will put that on

Comment: @RyanJ's point is important because I've seen cases where Java-8-with-compliance-for-7 doesn't flag the same compile issues that a true java 7 compile will -- namely syntax subtleties with generic types and raw declarations